# How to have a caption of the imageimport to Latex vertically similar to image?

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I want to have a large figure to plot vertically in one full page in latex, but the caption is not shown vertically, but rather horizontally.

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\section{One}
tesing testing tesing testing tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

\begin{figure}[!b]
        \centering
            % \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                \includegraphics[scale=1.6, angle=90]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 1}
            \label{fig:arm1}
          \end{figure}
    %

\clearpage

\section{two}
 testing

\end{document}
```

My plot outcome is:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `figure` environment in a `landscape` environment from the `pdflscape` package and remove the `angle` option as shown in the following example.

Side note: What's the reason for the `\subcaption` command? There is only one image and no corresponding `\caption` in the figure?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\section{One}
tesing testing tesing testing tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=1.6]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 1}
            \label{fig:arm1}
          \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}

\clearpage

\section{two}
 testing

\end{document}
```

If you prefer to keep the figure floating, use `sidewaysfigure` from the `rotating` package:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\section{One}
tesing testing tesing testing tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing



\begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=1.6]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 1}
            \label{fig:arm1}
          \end{sidewaysfigure}


\section{two}
 testing

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Did I make any mistake? I try copy and paste your code, and the output is horizontally image, different from your imaga.

Comment: @aan: In the resulting pdf document the whole page will be rotated resulting in you seeing the image as horizontal. Alternatively, you can also try with the `lscape` package. If you want your image to keep floating, go for the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the `rotating` package instead.

Comment: thanks. you are correct. Is my mistake didn't see it clearly. Thanks once again. Brillant!

Comment: @leadriis, can i know am I still able to use `[h!]` for the figure positioning? It seemed like have a large space before the image. I understand that the image in a new page. Do you suggest using `sidewaysfigure`?

Comment: @aan: Which package/environment to use depends on how ou want the figure to behave. If you want it to float, use `sidwwaysfigure`. If you don't want it to float, use `landscape`.

Comment: thanks. Now i can understand. However, I found another problem. the page number is gone and those heater also missing in image page.

Comment: @aan: With which package/environment combination?

Comment: @leadriis, I am using `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` for page number.

Comment: This seems to be a bit more complicated. Please prepare a compilable MWE and post a follow up question.

Comment: thanks a lot. After I checked (making a MWE), I found that is my mistake, which i set the image too large until the header and page number gone. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: i had another link question with this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523007/how-can-i-maximize-the-size-of-the-image-when-i-am-using-landscape